# select on nvarchar(max) column really slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2008 R2. I'm doing a select on a table with ~70,000 rows.
If I try to query an nvarchar(max) column, where the longest string is 2,433 characters, it takes 66 seconds.

```
select Comment from StudentAssessmentComments
```

Filtering by an indexed column to 17,000 rows still takes ~17 seconds.

```
select Comment from StudentAssessmentComments where FileYear = 2016
```

If I query a different, unindexed column, its immediate (< 1sec).

```
select StaffID from StudentAssessmentComments
```

Is it normal for an nvarchar(max) column to perform so badly? If not, does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The purpose of the index is to speed up your query search. So based on your results for time taken, your unindexed column performs way faster. This is mostly due to your server database connection. Is your server located very far away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to guess that you have a relatively slow network connection to the database.  The two timings you give are both pretty close to 1,000 rows per second.

If a typical row had 1,000 characters, then this would be about 2,000 bytes (wide characters) and about 2 Mbytes/second.  That seems on the slow side, but it is not unreasonable.

So, my best guess is that this is your "network" connection to the database, so there is not much you can do about it if you need tens of thousands of rows with the full comments.

Comment: Just tried running it directly on the server. Less than a second. Feeling pretty dumb. The network environment here should be waaay better than that, so didn't even think of it. Thanks Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

It is abasically need to redesign your source of data insert and apply some limitation and fine tune the process but meantime, for quick workaround to make your select statement work faster is to limit the characters to be displayed using select SUBSTRING (nvarchar max column name, 1, 5000). Hope it helps.